# trait - get implemented class from trait

Tags: php, traits

I have following trait implementation:

```
static function getNextHashId($class)
{
    $data = DB::table("information_schema.TABLES")
        ->where("TABLE_SCHEMA", env('DB_DATABASE'))
        ->where("TABLE_NAME", with(new static)->getTable())
        ->pluck("AUTO_INCREMENT")[0];
    return Hashids::connection($class)->encode($data);
}
```

But when I have many class implementing the traits, it's not efficient since I need to pass class to the method.

```
   Class1::getNextHashId(Class1::class);
   Class2::getNextHashId(Class2::class);
```

Is it possible to remove get class from traits? so I just need to write `Class1::getNextHashId();`
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

After having further search it can be done by static binding.

```
return Hashids::connection(static::class)->encode($data);
```